# Where list of generators configure keys?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-generate, rails-generators

Where list or how to fetch list of generators keys (`assets`,`template_engine`) for disabling like this:

```
config.generators do |g|
  g.assets false
  g.template_engine false
end
```

When execute `rails generate` it show generators list. It is possible to disable `assets` generator because it showed by command. But how to guess or fetch key name `template_engine` and so on keys to disable?